# how to limit a scatterviewitem within the scatter view boundary? - Surface SDK

Tags: c#, wpf

I have fullscreen scatter view control and I have one scatter view item inside it. When I drag scatter view item it allows me to drag item outside the scatter view boundary. How I can restrict it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by registering manipulation delta event and get the center point value, By this I restrict the scatter view item within the scatter view boundaries.

svi.IsManipulationEnabled = true;

svi.AddHandler(UIElement.ManipulationDeltaEvent, new EventHandler(svi_ManipulationDelta), true);